# What is the purpose of automatically creating statistics for a non-indexed column?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In SQL server, creating an index automatically creates statistics object for that index and uses it to decide best query execution plan.

Also, statistics object is automatically created for columns used in the WHERE clause - for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM AWSales 
WHERE ProductID = 898
```

The above query automatically creates a statistics object for ProductID. What purpose does this serve?

Since the non-indexed column is unsorted, and it is also not a B-tree structure, then how does statistics help to choose a better query plan than a table scan?

I thought the purpose of statistics was to allow the engine to choose between using an index or not; and whether to use seek or scan. What knowledge am I missing?

Comment: It is useful to know if a query operator is going to return 1 or 1 million rows (or 10 or 1000 different values for those rows), regardless of how indexes are used to select the data. It's crucial to decide between using a hash, loop or merge join, for example, as well as how much memory to reserve for a result set. For *this particular query*, the statistics are likely not useful, but they are so useful generally (and cheap enough to produce by sampling) that the optimizer just goes ahead and creates them anyway. Making a decision on statistics while compiling would be much more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It serves the same purpose as the statistics created for the index. It will use the statistics for estimates to choose the best execution plan based on CPU time and I/O's. The plan with the lowest cost will be selected.

When the indexes on the table do not cover the column in the where clause, so ProductID, in your example, it will create statistics on the column to create the histogram to sniff the estimates for the value you've supplied unless it already has a cached plan.

In your execution plan you can see what statistics the engine used to pick the plan by viewing the properties on the SELECT object in the plan (the left most object). Expand the OptimizerStatsUsage property.

Comment: HI, But the non indexed columns are not sorted. And neither are they in B-Tree structure. So how exactly does statistic help. Can you give me an example please. I am thinking that it will always do a table scan.

Comment: @variable, in your trivial query the engine will do a scan. But imagine you have to join other tables so how could  the engine choose the join type? Should it choose HASH, MERGE or LOOP joins? It depends on the rows count which one the engine will take from statistics.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.